# Can a java POJO API response be converted to match a Map<String, String> data type?

Tags: java

My assertion is failing because of data type conversion:

```
public void verify(Map<String, String> theNames) {
List <DemoResponse> DemoResponse = Arrays.asList(BaseService.getResponse().as(DemoResponse.class));

System.out.println(demoResponse);
System.out.println(theNames);

}
```

The argument `Map<String, String> theNames` is fetching data from a cucumber feature file and returns the expected output:

```
{name=Builder, description=Builder demo, id=ye208bq4-2485-8nd3-10ka-92f4cb91795x}
```

DemoResponse POJO class returns the output:

```
DemoResponse(id=ye208bq4-2485-8nd3-10ka-92f4cb91795x, name=Builder, description=Builder demo)
```

The two outputs obviously have the same properties, but different formats, so they are not equal

As a result, this assertion comparing inequality passes:

```
assertThat(demoResponse).isNotEqualTo(theNames);
```

But this assertion comparing equality fails:

```
assertThat(demoResponse).isEqualTo(theName);
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to make the two formats equal so that the failing assertion would pass.

This is the POJO class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder

public class DemoResponse{

  private UUID id;
  private String name;
  private String description;

}
```

In a bid to make the outputs match, I tried to convert the POJO response to a `Map` this way:

```
List demoResponse = Arrays.asList( BaseService.getResponse().as(DemoResponse.class));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<List<DemoResponse>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<DemoResponse>>() {/* */};
List<DemoResponse> res = mapper.convertValue(demoResponse,  typeReference);

System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
[DemoResponse(id=ye208bq4-2485-8nd3-10ka-92f4cb91795x, name=Builder, description=Builder demo)]
```

The output changed slightly from the previous approach but still did not match the format output from `Map<String, String> theNames`.

How do I get the format of the two outputs to match? I don't mind changing the data type of any of the two, as long as their outputs match, I would be ecstatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert any class to a map and vice-versa, you can do as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DemoResponse foo = new DemoResponse(UUID.randomUUID(), "name", "description");

// Convert POJO to Map
Map<String, Object> map =
        mapper.convertValue(foo, new TypeReference<>() {
        });

// Convert Map to POJO
DemoResponse anotherFoo = mapper.convertValue(map, DemoResponse.class);
```

Just have in mind that, in the class DemoResponse, you must have a default constructor (no args) and possibly either getters/setters or the fields annotated with

```java
@JsonProperty
```

After that, you can either convert your POJO to a map or convert the map of values to a POJO and perform the desired assertions.

Comment: could you please take a look at this question to see if its something you are able to answer, Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167903/is-there-a-way-to-pass-api-request-body-as-a-map-variable-in-a-pojo-builder-clas

Answer (score 1):

you are comparing List and Map which are not the same object, thus they are not equal. you can try to convert the POJO into map first:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
Map<String, String> demoResponse = mapper.convertValue(BaseService.getResponse(), new TypeReference<Map<String,String>>() {});
```

then you can check using this:

```
assertThat(demoResponse).isEqualTo(theNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a basic response because you have only 3 fields and equals matching class, you need only to create an DemoResponse with the Map<String, String>, maybe with a constructor.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder

public class DemoResponse{

  private UUID id;
  private String name;
  private String description;

  public DemoResponse(Map<String, String> theNames){
     this.id = theNames.get("id");
     this.name = theNames.get("name");
     this.description = theName.get("description");
  }
}
```

And after you can assert like that

```
assertThat(demoResponse).isEqualTo(new DemoResponse(theName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your line

```
    TypeReference<List<DemoResponse>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<DemoResponse>>() {/* */};
List<DemoResponse> res = mapper.convertValue(demoResponse,  typeReference);
```

to

```
    TypeReference<DemoResponse> typeReference = new TypeReference<DemoResponse>() {/* */};
DemoResponse res = mapper.convertValue(demoResponse,  typeReference);
```

And you will get what you want. You are parsing a single value as a List and because of that your value is surrounded by [] which is your difference