# Is there a way to pass API request body as a map variable in a POJO builder class?

Tags: java, cucumber-java

I have trawled the net but was unable to crack this one.

With the help of lombok's `@Builder`, I successfully built an API request body `demo` via a POJO class and the body works as expected when I passed it in my API request:

```
public static void payload() {
        DemoRequest demo = DemoRequest.builder()
                .demoNumber("test1")
                .demoId("test2")
                .demoName("test3")
                .batch("test4")
                .col("test5")
                .build();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> mapResponse = mapper.convertValue(demo, new TypeReference<>() {
        });

        System.out.println(mapResponse);
}
```

Output:

```
{demoNumber=test1, demoId=test2, demoName=test3, batch=test4, col=test5}
```

Now, the challenge. I do not want to pass the values `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4`, `test5` in the `payload()` method, instead, I want to pass them from a cucumber-java feature file so that whenever I call `payload()`, I can pass a `map` variable holding the values. I want `payload()` to be dynamic.

The variable holding the values looks like this:

```
 @Given("I have created a payload (.*)$")
  public static void createPayload(Map<String, String>requestBody) { //Map<String, String>requestBody is holding the values coming from cucumber
          
    System.out.println(requestBody);
}
```

Output:

```
{demoNumber=test1, demoId=test2, demoName=test3, batch=test4, col=test5}
```

But I want to be able to do this:

```
payload(requestBody);
```

So the big question is: can I pass the values as a `Map<String, String>requestBody` variable inside of `payload()`, something like this:

```
private static Object createPayload(Map<String, String> requestBody) {

...

.build();

}
```

So that I can supply the values when I call payload()

```
public void createPayload(Map<String, String>requestBody) { 
    
payload(requestBody);

}
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Well, you just have to add a method parameter to `payload()` method. I don't see that you have tried to do anything like this.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer can you demonstrate it, please? Thanks

Comment: I got your request. I will take a look as soon as I can, but I am quite busy right now. It might be maybe a day or two before I can reply.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I follow your issue... If you just want to add another field to your DemoResponse, why don't you just add that field and a method to set it in the Builder? What is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Like pgeadas, I do not understand the issue. The way I took  this was that, instead of having a hard-coded payload in the step definition method, you want to dynamically assign the values to the (generic) payload object? If so, why not use a `DataTable`?